# Azure Fluent Authentication Never Returns

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-fluent-api

I'm attempting to use the Azure Fluent Resource Management and seem unable to login. The "

> Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Authenticate

method fails to return. Considering the code below, api.Authenticate never returns and no exception is ever caught. I am confident the credentials are correct as I use them elsewhere.

```
        try
        {
            var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
                .FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

            var api = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Configure();
            var authenticated = api.Authenticate(credentials);
            var subscribed = authenticated.WithDefaultSubscriptionAsync();

            return await subscribed;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code to create the RestClient and pass that into Authenticate method and this seems to work. Not really sure why, I looked on Microsoft's GitHub and can't see a reason for this. Regardless, if anyone is having a similar issue, give this a go!